# Spawn a new terminal window from the terminal

Tags: terminal, osx, terminal-emulator

Is there any terminal command I can execute that will pop open a new terminal window?

I need something that will work in OSX' Terminal.app, but it would be nice if there were a way to do this that works on any common terminal emulator.

Comment: The terminal emulator [`xterm`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) is nearly everywhere installed.

Comment: `xterm &` will work but on OSX you'll need the X11 app installed. I can't recall if it is by default or has to be installed separately (xcode?)

Answer (score 2):

Other than typing `xterm` I believe on OSX you do this:

```
$ open -a Terminal.app bash
```

I think you can also do this:

```
$ /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal
```

#### References

- [Programmatically launch Terminal.app with a specified command (and custom colors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404242/programmatically-launch-terminal-app-with-a-specified-command-and-custom-colors)